# How to get file name from Sharepoint Asset Library

Tags: rest, sharepoint, assets

How can I get the file name of an image from a SharePoint 2013 Asset Library?

I am trying to write a JQuery/REST snippet to search a subset of images within the library, based on their other column values and display them. I would use `FileLeafRef` in case of a Document Library, but I couldn't find an equivalent field in Asset Library.

I so far tried the following, neither returns file name:
https:///crm/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Publication%20List')/items?select=File/Name&expand=File
https:///crm/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Publication%20List')/items?select=FileLeafRef

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a *typo* in your example, in particular `$` symbol is *missing* for `$select` and `$expand` query options ([more details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx#bk_supported)).

The following rest endpoints demonstrate how to retrieve file name from Assets library:

1) Using `FileLeafRef` property:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('<list title>')/items?$select=FileLeafRef
```

2) Using `File/Name` property:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/items?$select=File/Name&$expand=File
```

3) Using `Folder/Files` property:

```
/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('<list url>')/files?$select=Name
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that yt's still `FileLeafRef` for an Asset Library. Any chance you could put the relevant code in your question?

Here's the rest endpoint for `FileLeafRef`:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('<list title>')/items?$select=FileLeafRef
```

Alternatively you could always use the `File Name` property:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('<list title>')/items?$select=File/Name&$expand=File
```

Comment: Tried both. Issue is not code specific (but I've updated the question). I put these URLs into the browser but get no file name returned.