# How to get folder names from SharePoint Asset Library

Tags: rest, sharepoint

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527575/how-to-get-file-name-from-sharepoint-asset-library) is the link to get file name. But I want to get the Folder names using REST query. Please Help

Answer (score 1):

For me it was "RootFolder/ServerRelativeUrl"

```
SharepointAPI.GetLists({params:{$select:"Id,Title,EntityTypeName,RootFolder/ServerRelativeUrl",$expand:"RootFolder"}}).$promise.then(function(result) {
...
});

    this.GetLists = function(params) {
        return {$promise:
          $http({
              method: 'GET'
              , url: app_web_url+"/_api/web/lists"
              , params: params.params
              , headers: {
                  "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
              }
          })
          .then(function(response) {
              return response.data;
          })
        };
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling this endpoint:

```
/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Site Assets')/Items?$expand=Folder&$select=Title,Folder/ServerRelativeUrl
```